# Is it possible to pick a movie from Videos app in iPad, make a copy of it or directly play it in our iOS app?

Tags: ios, ipad, swift4, itunes, mpmediaplayercontroller

Our requirement is to embed/copy all the videos that are transferred to iPad from Mac using iTunes in our iOS app so that they can play the videos from our app itself using AVPlayer instead of using default Videos app.

Is this possible? If so how? I looked into MPMediaLibrary but couldn't get any working sample or any info regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a share sheet extension, which the video can then be shared into your app. From there you can play it in your video player.

This is a good tutorial for share sheet extensions, if you need one: https://www.9spl.com/blog/build-share-extension-ios-using-swift/